# decomposition of order preseving injective map $\phi:[n-k] \to [n]$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-topology

Let $d^j:[n-1]\to [n]$ be the order preserving injection that skip $\{j\}$  in the range,where $[n] = \{0,...,n\}$.

Prove the following two fact:

1. Let $\phi:[n-k] \to [n]$ is  the injective order preserving map,then it has unique composition of the form :$\phi = d^{j_k}...d^{j_1}$ where $0\le j_1<...<j_k\le n$
2. $d^id^j = d^{j+1}d^i$ with $i\le j$.

I have no idea how to prove these theorems formally,I can check these two facts holds,but seems a bit messy to prove it

Comment: What do you mean when you say $\phi$ is "the" injective order preserving map? You can inject $[n-k]$ into $[n]$ while preserving the order in many different ways, or am I missing something?

Comment: @Paulo Mourão ,here order preserving means if $i\le j$ then we have $\phi(i)\le \phi(j)$.There may be many way to inject $[n-j]$ into $[n]$ the question is given one particular such map,we can always decompose it into sequence of $d^i$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d^j$ is explicitly given by
$$d^j(r) =  \begin{cases} r & r < j \\ r+1 & r \ge j  \end{cases}$$

No. 2. :

We have $j \ge i$.
For $r \ge j$ we get $r+1 \ge i$, $r+1 \ge j+1$ and $r \ge i$ and therefore
$$d^i d^j(r) = d^i(r+1) = r+2 = d^{j+1}(r+1) = d^{j+1} d^i(r)$$
For $j > r \ge i$ we get $r+1 < j+1$ and therefore
$$d^i d^j(r) = d^i(r) = r+1 = d^{j+1}(r+1) = d^{j+1} d^i(r)$$
For $i > r$ we get $j+1 > r$ and therefore
$$d^i d^j(r) = d^i(r) = r = d^{j+1}(r) = d^{j+1} d^i(r)$$

No. 1. :

We do it by induction. For technical reasons let us consider order preserving injections $\phi : [n] \to [n+k]$. The base case $k = 1$ is obvious because there is a unique $j_1 \in [n+1]$ which is not in the image of $\phi$. Hence $\phi = d^{j_1}$.For the step $k \mapsto k+1$ pick any element $s_{k+1} \in [n+k+1] \setminus \phi([n])$. Define $$\phi' : [n] \to [n+k], \phi'(i) = \begin{cases} \phi(i) & \phi(i) < s_{k+1} \\ \phi(i)-1 & \phi(i) > s_{k+1} \end{cases}$$
This is an order preserving injection such that $\phi = d^{s_{k+1}}  \phi'$. Write $\phi'  = d^{s_k} \ldots d^{s_1}$ with $0 \le s_1 < \ldots < s_k \le n+k$. Thus $\phi = d^{s_{k+1}} d^{s_k} \ldots d^{s_1}$. If $s_k < s_{k+1}$ we set $j_r = s_r$ and are done. If $s_k \ge s_{k+1}$, we use 2. to get $\phi = d^{s_k+1} d^{s_{k+1}} d^{s_{k-1}} \ldots d^{s_1}$ where $s_{k+1} < s_k+1$. If $s_{k-1} \ge s_{k+1}$ we repeat this procedure and shift $d^{s_{k+1}}$ one position to the right. Continue this procedure until $s_r < s_{k+1}$ for some $r$ or until $d^{s_{k+1}}$ has been shifted to the last position. Then $\phi = d^{s_k+1} \ldots d^{s_{r+1}+1} d^{s_{k+1}} d^{s_r} \ldots d^{s_1}$ or $\phi = d^{s_k+1} \ldots d^{s_1+1} d^{s_{k+1}}$. By construction the sequence of upper induces is strictly increasing from right to left.